# Why am I banned from answering questions when I have no existing answers?

Tags: support

I'm trying to fix the answer ban against my account but when I go to see my existing answers, in order to improve them, I see that I have no existing answers.

So, how do I remove the answer ban from my account?

Why am I banned when I have no existing answers?

Comment: Do you have really no existing or just a number of deleted answers actually?

Answer (score 11):

You have three deleted answers that are older than the threshold used for the recently deleted posts entry in your profile:

- [Appboy SDK iOS, the unreadCardCountForCategories delegate doesn't gives count for an updated card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37889324/appboy-sdk-ios-the-unreadcardcountforcategories-delegate-doesnt-gives-count-fo/43637329#43637329)
- [iOS 7: How to get own number via private API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19504478/ios-7-how-to-get-own-number-via-private-api/29853704#29853704)
- [Save many-to-one relationship from JSON into Core Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2966498/save-many-to-one-relationship-from-json-into-core-data/14835087#14835087)

All three were questions asked in answers, and deleted as such. There's no way to save these by editing.

This is one of those cases where you could use the contact form and request dissociating these posts from your account. Moderators can't do this, but SE employees can. That might be the only way you'll be able to lift this ban.

Comment: Actually, by asking good questions and doing good edits he may go out the ban. Disassociation doesn't fix it. And SE still takes them into account for the ban.

Comment: Ok, yes, now I see the issue, even though those deleted questions do not appear in my profile and one is years old. I have filled out the contact form and await judgement.

I'll try to ask good questions in the future to get out of the ban but it's kind of hard to figure out when I will escape the ban.

Comment: @Braiam do you have a source for that as I recall seeing several comments/answers from employees to "why can't I ask/answer" meta questions about diassociation being a possible option in extreme cases.

Comment: Someone who is answer-banned based on ancient non-answers that were voted down and deleted doesn't have a lot of ways of working out of that. It's one of the few cases where dissociation makes sense, because odds are they won't repeat those actions (unlike people with a history of asking low-quality questions).

Comment: @psubsee2003 "we have always recorded disassociations, and moderators can currently find a list of every post that's ever been disassociated from a profile. It's just not in a convenient place that moderators frequently look, so it tends to go unnoticed" ([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/300637/allow-users-to-anonymize-their-posts-themselves/300658?noredirect=1#comment977366_300658))

Comment: @BradLarson ^^^ see above - it is quite likely that ban algorithm takes disassociated posts into account. For the case of the OP they may have better luck [re-starting the account at 1 post/week rate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234610/165773) (unless they already did that)

Comment: @gnat Brad's correct here.... disassociation (although recorded) isn't taken into account by the system (I've seen it used and have requested it once or twice) when it comes to calculating whether an account is Q/A-banned as it's though the account never made the post(s) (in this case there would be no answers to look against to calculate a ban). The issue that gnat raises is allowing users to self-disassociate posts - which at the moment using the current implementation would enable people to walk away completely from posts with downvotes and any blocks put in place because of those.

Comment: (eg: at the moment disassociation is fairly sledgehammer like - it removes the post from a users' account. So it can be used in cases such as removing posts from being considered for a QA ban or in some cases where a user has gotten reputation from plag'ing an answer that's gone unnoticed for more than 60 days meaning they get to keep the rep when it's deleted. Getting the answer disassociated from their account is a way of removing that rep for instance @gnat)